# Get CSS isolation in a .Net 5 MVC application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, .net-5

Is there a way to get CSS isolation working in a .Net 5 MVC application?
I tried it with different setups, but the css bundle won't show up. Am I missing something, or does it only work in .Net 6?

Comment: I believe this is a new, upcoming feature for ASP.NET Core 6 MVC only - not present in .NET 5. For more info see: https://dotnetthoughts.net/css-isolation-in-aspnet-core-mvc6/

Comment: I'm afraid you are right, but I was hoping that there is a way to opt in to css isolation in .NET 5 somehow...